# Apply same function on same object, with different parameters -- the tidy way

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to apply iteratively the same function (in the example, `my_function`) to the same object (here, `my_matrix`) with different parameters (`my_parameters`) stored in a list, or something similar.

The reprex is:

```
library(tidyverse)
my_matrix <- replicate(10, sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
my_parameters <- tibble(value1 = sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE),
                        value2 = sample(2:3, 5, replace = TRUE))
my_function <- function(param1, param2, matrix) {
    (matrix + param1) * param2
}
new_matrix <- my_matrix
for (i in seq.int(nrow(my_parameters))) {
    new_matrix <- my_function(my_parameters$value1[[i]], my_parameters$value2[[i]], new_matrix)
}
new_matrix
```

(I guess I could compute everything in one iteration with a clever factorization, but this is just to illustrate the problem.)

Is there a tidy function, like:

```
magical_function(my_matrix, my_function, my_parameters)
```

that would do the trick?

So far, I dug into `purrr`, but `accumulate`, or similar functions, does not seem to apply here.

Of note, I am aware that factorization does not (directly) apply here, and that could explain why there is no obvious answer here (as far as I know).

Comment: would the final answer be one `new_matrix` or list of matrices? Do you need `map2(my_parameters$value1, my_parameters$value2, my_function, matrix = my_matrix)` ?

Comment: No, the OP wants a final matrix where each iteration uses the previous one to be multiplied by the next parameter values.

Comment: @cimentadaj: Precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using `tidyverse` where we use the `reduce2` and pass the matrix (`original_matrix`) in `.init` so that it will be used as the first value to start the accumulation.  Note that, the `..1`, `..2` etc. notation is used when there are more than 2 objects passed into the function.  The `..1` signifies the `original_matrix`, and the other two in the same order as the 'x', 'y' parameters

```
library(purrr)
reduce2(my_params$x, my_params$y, ~ (..1 + ..2) * ..3, .init = original_matrix)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]  656  512  704  464  368  560  560  560  704   368
# [2,]  704  752  560  416  368  752  416  464  608   752
# [3,]  512  560  560  608  416  608  704  320  752   464
# [4,]  704  656  464  752  512  656  752  416  656   416
# [5,]  416  656  320  464  416  464  416  464  368   752
# [6,]  416  416  752  608  656  320  368  320  320   608
# [7,]  464  368  608  416  416  560  464  752  320   368
# [8,]  752  416  704  512  608  368  320  464  608   560
# [9,]  368  560  368  512  464  368  608  512  368   320
#[10,]  560  368  464  560  656  416  704  704  320   464
```

If we want to check how the values are getting changed in each run, use the `accumulate2`

```
accumulate2(my_params$x, my_params$y, ~ (..1 + ..2) * ..3, .init = original_matrix)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(23131)
original_matrix <- replicate(10, sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
my_params <- tibble(x = sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE),
                    y = sample(2:3, 5, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Most interesting.  Although I guess it does not extend to more than 2 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

So I've been thinking about this and I'm not sure there's a 'clean' tidy way of doing it. `purrr` is all about functional programming, which means that any iteration is independent of the other. As you say, `accumulate` and `reduce` can't solve this (at least without other type of checks). One way to do this would be to update your desired matrix using `<<-`. Below is an example that matches your results:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(23131)
original_matrix <- replicate(10, sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
my_params <- tibble(x = sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE),
                    y = sample(2:3, 5, replace = TRUE))

# Define the matrix that will be updated in each iteration
my_matrix <- original_matrix
my_function2 <- function(param1, param2) {
  # In each iteration, multiply by your params
  # and update `my_matrix` in the global environment

  # This ensures that in every interation you're getting
  # the up to date `my_matrix`.

  my_matrix <<- (my_matrix + param1) * param2

  my_matrix
}

final_res <- map2(my_params$x,
                  my_params$y,
                  my_function2)

final_res[[nrow(my_params)]]
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]  656  512  704  464  368  560  560  560  704   368
#>  [2,]  704  752  560  416  368  752  416  464  608   752
#>  [3,]  512  560  560  608  416  608  704  320  752   464
#>  [4,]  704  656  464  752  512  656  752  416  656   416
#>  [5,]  416  656  320  464  416  464  416  464  368   752
#>  [6,]  416  416  752  608  656  320  368  320  320   608
#>  [7,]  464  368  608  416  416  560  464  752  320   368
#>  [8,]  752  416  704  512  608  368  320  464  608   560
#>  [9,]  368  560  368  512  464  368  608  512  368   320
#> [10,]  560  368  464  560  656  416  704  704  320   464
```

Comment: That is very interesting, although the use of `<<-` looks like a red flag to me...

Comment: @akrun's answer is actually much better.